# How to apply callcc so that it provides an escape continuation mechanism for use with the continuation monad

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, continuations, callcc

I try to implement the continuation monad in Javascript to handle continuation passing style and asynchronous control flows. Here is my continuation monad for learning:

```js
// auxiliary functions

const log = prefix => x => console.log(prefix, x);
const addk = x => y => k => setTimeout((x, y) => k(x + y), 0, x, y);
const inck = x => k => setTimeout(x => k(x + 1), 0, x);
const sqr = x => x * x;


// continuation monad

const cont = {
  of: x => k => k(x),

  map: ftor => f => k => ftor(x => k(f(x))),

  ap: ftor => gtor => k => ftor(x => gtor(f => k(f(x)))),

  chain: ftor => mf => k => ftor(x => mf(x) (k)),

  callcc: f => k => f(x => () => k(x)) (k)
};


// map a normal, unary function with an asynchronous function:

cont.map(inck(9)) (sqr) (log("map"));


// chain two asynchronous CPS computations with an asynchronous binary CPS function

const comp1 = cont.map(inck(4)) (sqr);
const comp2 = cont.map(inck(9)) (sqr);

cont.chain(comp1) (x => cont.chain(comp2) (y => addk(x) (y))) (log("chain"));
```

Apart from `cont.ap`, whose benefit doesn't reveal itself to me, everything works fine.

Now I'd like to mimic the `throw`/`catch` mechanism of synchronous control flows in Javascript. `callcc` seems to fit, because it provides an escape continuation mechanism for use with continuation monads, as stated on [http://hackage.haskell.org/](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#v:callCC).

But I can't figure out how to apply `callcc` and I haven't found any suitable source that describes such an application.

Comment: Just as an aside, highly recommend using something like `R.curryN` over manually currying all your functions http://ramdajs.com/docs/#curryN

Comment: @JaredSmith there is no Rambda tag on this question. Also, what is the basis of your recommendation?

Comment: @Jared I consider it the other way around: Why should I use a programmatic curry solution when I have arrow functions with little syntactic overhead in my tool set?

Comment: @naomik could just as easily have said `_.curry`, I just prefer ramda. As for the why, I personally prefer the flexibility of being able to pass any number of arguments or one at a time.

Comment: @ftor, James Long does a good series on this: ["What is a continuation?"](http://jlongster.com/Whats-in-a-Continuation), ["Implementing a stepping debugger in JavaScript"](http://jlongster.com/Implementing-Stepping-Debugger-JavaScript), and ["Exploring Continuations: Resumable Exceptions"](http://jlongster.com/Exploring-Continuations-Resumable-Exceptions). He uses a utility he wrote, called [Unwinder](https://github.com/jlongster/unwinder), which is mostly just a exploration/demonstration of how call/cc can be implemented in JS. Disclaimer: it's all very highly involved.

Comment: @JaredSmith there is no lodash or underscore tag on this question.

Comment: @ftor YMMV, after all its not that hard to write your own implementation if that's the way you swing. For trivial examples or your own code it almost certainly doesn't matter, but if your exporting an API for the benefit of others saying something like `f(3)('foo')(true)` is less idiomatic for JS than `f(3, 'foo', true)`.

Comment: @naomik: Thanks for the unwinder link. Looks promising!

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm positive you are trying to be helpful but your comments are off-topic – this isn't a question about how/why to curry (or not to curry) functions. Also, your personal preference doesn't make a very good supporting argument.

Comment: @ftor you're going to be a little disappointed, I'm sure. Unwinder involves a "pre-compile" step, of sorts. And the author recommends against using it on production code. I think there are just some features that can't be implemented without support from the language itself.

Comment: @Jared I think mathematical curried functions are less idiomatic for ES5 but not for ES6 (=> arrow functions). But it is OK if we disagree on this issue.

Comment: @ftor for writing reading code, totally agree with you. I was more considering it from the caller's perspective. If the caller is you, no problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Continuations in a Nutshell

Continuations are a powerful abstraction. Let me emphasize that. Continuations are an **immensely** powerful abstraction. Why are continuations so powerful? It's because a continuation is simply a function<sup>[1]</sup> and [“functions have a dangerous property of being invokable.”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577492/783743) More on that later.

### So, if a continuation is just a function then why is it so special?

Yes, a continuation is just a function. However, what makes a continuation so special is what it represents. A continuation represents the “rest of the computation” (a.k.a. the computation context). For example, consider the following Scheme expression:

```lisp
  (add1 (* 3 x))
;       |_____|
;          |
;     computation

  (add1 [])
; |_______|
;     |
;  context
```

Here the computation `(* 3 x)` has the context `(add1 [])` where the `[]` represents a hole. The hole can be plugged with the result of a computation. This is written as `(add1 [result])` for some `result`. A continuation is just a representation of a context. For example, the function `(lambda (result) (add1 result))` represents the context `(add1 [])`.

On the other hand, the computation `(* 3 x)` can also be represented as a function. It's represented as the function `(lambda (context) (context (* 3 x)))` where `context` is a continuation representing the context of the computation. In should be noted that the [`Cont`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Cont.html#t:Cont) type in Haskell represents the computation itself, not its context.

### Okay, but what makes continuations so powerful?

As I said before, a continuation is simply a function and [“functions have a dangerous property of being invokable.”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577492/783743) In particular, a function may be invoked not only once but also arbitrarily many times or even never at all. This is what makes continuations so powerful.

For example, consider the aforementioned computation `(* 3 x)` represented as a function:

```lisp
(lambda (context)
  (context (* 3 x)))
```

What if we applied `context` more than once? We could use it to double the result as follows:

```lisp
(lambda (context)
  (+
    (context (* 3 x))
    (context (* 3 x))))
```

If the given `context` is `add1` then this will produce the answer `(* 2 (add1 (* 3 x)))`.

On the other hand, what if we never applied `context`? We could short-circuit the evaluation:

```lisp
(lambda (context)
  (* 3 x))
```

This is precisely what `call/cc` does. It short-circuits the evaluation by ignoring the context and simply returning an answer. For example, consider:

```lisp
(call/cc (lambda (short-circuit)
  (add1 (short-circuit (* 3 x)))))
```

Here, the computation `(* 3 x)` has the context `add1`. However, we short-circuited the computation by applying the context of `call/cc` (i.e. `short-circuit`) to the result of the computation. Hence, we ignored the original context (i.e. `add1`) and returned an answer.

### How is `call/cc` implemented?

Now that we understand continuations let's look at the definition of [`callCC`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#v:callCC) in Haskell:

```hs
callCC :: ((a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r a) -> Cont r a
       -- |___________________________|
       --               |
       --               f
callCC f = Cont $ \k -> runCont (f (\a -> Cont $ \_ -> k a)) k
       --        __|___            |______________________|
       --       |      |                       |
       --       (a -> r)                 short-circuit
```

It should be noted that `k` is the current continuation (i.e. the continuation of the entire expression). The function `f` is the only input to `callCC`. It returns a `Cont r a` which represents the entire computation to be performed. We apply it to `k` to get the result of the computation.

However, inside the computation we can call `short-circuit` whenever we want to short-circuit the evaluation. This function takes a result and returns a computation that ignores its context and applies the current continuation `k` to the result, thereby short-circuiting the evaluation.

### Putting it all together in JavaScript.

We understood what continuations are in Scheme. We understood how `callCC` works in Haskell. Let's use our newfound knowledge to implement continuations and `callCC` in JavaScript:

```js
var Cont = defclass({
    constructor: function (runCont) {
        this.runCont = runCont;
    },
    map: function (f) {
        return new Cont(k => this.runCont(x => k(f(x))));
    },
    apply: function (g) {
        return new Cont(k => this.runCont(f => g.runCont(x => k(f(x)))));
    },
    bind: function (f) {
        return new Cont(k => this.runCont(x => f(x).runCont(k)));
    }
});

Cont.of = x => new Cont(k => k(x));

var callCC = f => new Cont(k => f(x => new Cont(_ => k(x))).runCont(k));

var log = prefix => x => console.log(prefix, x);

var add1 = x => Cont.of(x + 1);

callCC(short_circuit => short_circuit(15).bind(add1)).runCont(log("short"));

callCC(short_circuit => Cont.of(15).bind(add1)).runCont(log("no short"));

function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}
```

### Beware, `callCC` can be used to implement `goto`.

The power of `callCC` allows you to create arbitrary control flow structures like `throw`, coroutines and even `goto` as can be seen here:

```js
var Cont = defclass({
    constructor: function (runCont) {
        this.runCont = runCont;
    },
    map: function (f) {
        return new Cont(k => this.runCont(x => k(f(x))));
    },
    apply: function (g) {
        return new Cont(k => this.runCont(f => g.runCont(x => k(f(x)))));
    },
    bind: function (f) {
        return new Cont(k => this.runCont(x => f(x).runCont(k)));
    }
});

Cont.of = x => new Cont(k => k(x));

var callCC = f => new Cont(k => f(x => new Cont(_ => k(x))).runCont(k));

var log = (x, ms) => new Cont(k => setTimeout(_ => k(console.log(x)), ms));

var omega = x => x(x); // This is a very dangerous function. Run `omega(omega)`.

callCC(omega).bind(cc => log("loop", 1000).bind(_ => cc(cc))).runCont(x => x);

function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}
```

This code is equivalent to:

```
forever:
    delay(1000);
    print("loop");
    goto forever;
```

Hence, you should be careful when working with continuations.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Continuations are usually implemented using first-class functions. However, in languages with first-class continuations like Scheme there's a distinction between continuations and functions. Nevertheless, even if a continuation is not a function it's still like a function in that it's invokable.

Comment: You can delete, edit, and later undelete your answer if you accidentally posted it prematurely.

Comment: I can't wait to read the rest of your answer, surely you'll not only hit on invokable functions as dangerous but also on continuations being equivalent to GOTO?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, @Aadit. I like your approach to explain `call/cc` by using examples in Scheme, Haskell and Javascript. I guess this Q&A is a good starting point for people, who want to play around with `cont`/`call/cc` in Javascript and if this leads to a few crashed browsers due to infinite `goto` loops - well, I am OK with that. Anyway, now that I have a better understanding of `call/cc` I wonder what happens if I pass `cont` to `EitherT`. Keeping `call/cc` in mind this tool set seems to be promising to handle asynchronous control flows in a lazy, unicast and monadic style.

Comment: @Aadit Why do you wrap `Cont` in an object? In other words, why `Cont.of = x => new Cont(k => k(x))` instead of `Cont.of = x => k => k(x)`? Is a continuation in Haskell wrapped too? Or do you just want to create a "continuation type" and the only way to create a type in Javascript consists in assigning methods to a prototype, so you need an object that references this prototype?

Comment: @ftor It's just so that we can use `map`, `apply` and `bind` as methods instead of functions. It's also so that we can implement `map`, `apply` and `bind` as generic functions. For example, you can implement a generic map as `var map = f => x => x.map(f);`. This `map` function is allows for partial application and works for any object which implements the `map` method. Hence, you can use it with continuations as well as arrays and any other type.

Comment: It is worth noting that you always need an auxiliary function like `run` when you deal with monads that contain functions as values, because the returned lambda is wrapped in a monad instance (an `Object` type in Javascript). It is the same with the `State` monad for instance.